# redirect non-www to www with http:// not working in webkit

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

(I have a redirect on my site that redirects non-www and non-https users to https://www.frostriver.com
However, in chrome and safari, when someone types in http://frostriver.com (including the 'http://' in the url field) they get a page cannot be found error.

Here's a few examples:
frostriver.com - redirects,
http://frostriver.com - error,
https://frostriver.com - error,
http://www.frostriver.com - redirects,
https://www.frostriver.com - works.

Here's my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.frostriver.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Thanks!
Troy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain `frostriver.com` doesn't have a DNS entry associated with it. So `frostriver.com` isn't pointing to your server, and therefor the user never gets redirected, but gets an error message.

However if you type `frostriver.com` in chrome without the `http://`, google will check if the domain points to a server. If not it will do a google search for `frostriver.com` and redirect to the first search-result, which is `www.frostriver.com/`

PS. I get the same error in Firefox, so I don't see the webkit connection here

PPS. I don't see any code in your htaccess that would redirect non-www to www.

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I didn't see that.  The client's network administrator setup the DNS, and when I checked frostriver.com it redirected to the www.  Also, the directive I'm using is any web traffic hitting port 80 is automatically redirected to the https://www version of the site.  Thanks for your help!